# What do the third and fourth arguments of the mat-palette function do (not the first/second) and how do I use those for my own components

Tags: css, angular-material

I know what this does:

```
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200);
```

Now the primary color will be A200.

However, what happens if there is more than two arguments?
Like such:

Example:

```
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);
```

Example taken from here:
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

What do A100 & A400 do in this case?

It would really nice to get a link to the corresponding documentation about those parameters where you drew your knowledge from.

I tried searching for docs, found nothing.

I tried playing around with it in my app, nothing changed.

EDIT:
If those are special color variations, then how do I use those in my own elements manually, e.g. color=„primary-1“, primary-2.

I want to apply those colors if my element is in a special state, such that it stands out from other elements which have the color primary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have that [documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-theme)

> These four hues represent, in order: the "default" hue, a "lighter" hue, a "darker" hue, and a "text" hue

Comment: I added one sentence to the bottom of my answer about how to use those values, which I forgot to include in my question since I wrongly assumed it’d be implicitly included in my question. Do you know the answer?

Comment: @chefLosangeles Well, that completely changes what you as for. And no, I don't know, I have never used angular-material

Comment: I found the answer myself, it's under this section:

You can also reference colors using the "default", "lighter", "darker", and "text" colors passed to define-palette.

In this link, the same as you provided:
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-theme: